# .sjoin Geopandas returns too many results

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

I have two dataframes, both containing geometry columns. The first dataframe contains `MULTIPOLYGONs` while the second one contains `POINTs`. My aim is to join the dataframes so each `POINT` will be assigned to corresponding `POLYGON`. `DF_polygons` has `2480` rows and `DF_points` has aroud `150.000` rows (10 tractors with GPS driving over fields, data coming in every few seconds).

I used this code to join dataframes (also tried `within` and `contains`):

```
points_in_polygons = gpd.sjoin(DF_points, DF_polygons, op='intersects', how='inner)
```

The problem is, it returns a result with approximately `30.000.000` rows in all 3 cases. The desirable result would have 100.000 rows - so *each unique point would be assigned to one of 2480 multipolygons*.

Is it possible that the problem is in overlapping polygons? How can I deal with it? Which packages should I use? I am completely new to GeoPandas.

Comment: I think you are better of if you look at each geometry separated. You will have to extract the shapely geometries from the dataframe and check for intersection

Comment: If i understand right, i need an efficient way to check the intersection between 2480 multipolygons?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve right now. do you just want to know if your polygons overlap or do you want a solution to your assignment problem?

Comment: If you want to check if they overlap, you can either do gpd.plot or save it as a shapefile and visualise it in qgis

Answer (score 1):

The reason of such a huge result was in overlapping polygons. To detect polygons that overlap i used this:

```
data_overlaps=gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs=df_polygons.crs)
for index, row in df_polygons.iterrows():
    data_temp1=df_polygons.loc[df_polygons.field_id!=row.field_id,]

# check if intersection occured
overlaps=data_temp1[data_temp1.geometry.overlaps(row.geometry)]['field_id'].tolist()
if len(overlaps)>0:
    temp_list=[]
    print(overlaps)
```